# Using an SD card for regular backups?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, sd-card

I recently updated to a 128 GB solid state drive, and I've gotta say, I love the boot times and app load times, however I'm not keen on the increased possibility of spontaneous failure. I figure I've still got a few years on this thing, so I'm not majorly concerned about it, however I do want to get a static backup plan in place.

I've been considering the possibility of simply popping a MicroSD card into the side of my laptop and making an rsync script of my home folder (Linux Mint by the way) to backup to that card on startup/shutdown/whenever I feel is a good time to back it up. Apart from the initial sync, The actual amount of data that I figure I would backup regularly would be relatively tiny; minor changes to files here and there, occasionally adding new songs to my music folder, the only files that would see daily activity would be my source code folder.

I've never had an SD card fail on me, but then again going with "I've never" anecdotes is poor preparation for the worst. I don't think it's very likely my ssd and the backup MicroSD cards would fail at the exact same time, but I'm concerned about how often I would have to replace the MicroSD card. Would a 64 gb or so class 10 microsd card stand up to daily backup use?

Comment: I think the question is rather "how well exactly would it stand up to daily backup use?". ;-) And also "how will you know when it does?". Also consider how easy that makes it to steal your data.

Comment: I suppose I hadn't considered those questions (which are both valid). I suppose for the second in my rsync script I could make a test to see if the drive viable (If it's a majorly time consuming test make it occur once a week). For the third one of course, I figure if someone has access to my laptop to take the card out, they're just gonna take the entire laptop anyway - The card would never leave the laptop unless it had failed (Then like all data devices I dispose of, it would be tossed into a [pool of lava](http://superuser.com/questions/17350/whats-the-life-expectancy-of-an-sd-card)

Comment: Yeah, the theft thing is really depending on your individual situation and a microSD is better than an SD i guess as it is more difficult to get out. Glad i could catalyse more thought. ;-) Good luck with your testing.

Comment: Interesting read techie, however I feel this is a slighly different situation. [Automatonic's thread](http://superuser.com/questions/254458/what-would-be-the-down-sides-to-backup-archival-via-sd-cards) was about using SD cards for long term storage, with concerns about how well they may hold the data. My question is more concerned with daily use and longevity from wear and tear.